# How to restrict specific bind to a a subission in XForms?

Tags: xforms, xsltforms

I have a set of `xforms:input` elements which are made required using the `xforms:bind`. However, I have two buttons (`xforms:submit`) on the form and for one of the buttons I do not want the input fields to be required. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

XForms Specifications say that it is possible to submit an invalid instance using @validate="false".

Because AVT is not yet supported for @validate by XSLTForms, two submissions have to be defined (one with @validate="false" and one without).